# External Date picker .js file not working while the validate .js file is working

Tags: php, jquery

I am using jQuery in php.
Plugin as jQuery-1.7.1.min.js

For validate: jQuery.validate.min.js

For date picker: jQuery-1.10.2.js, jQuery-ui.js

If I added the script tag in following manner validate js file is worked

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

If I added the script tag in following manner datepicker js file is worked

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Both are not working in the same time.
Is there any wrong in my code?
Please help to solve this problem...

Comment: are there any console errors mate..??

Comment: Why are you including two different versions of jQuery? That is not going to work.

Comment: Do not mix jQuery version. Just remove the 1.7. If you mean [jqueryvalidation.org](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) it was tested with `1.6.4, 1.7.2, 1.8.3, 1.9.1, 1.11.1`
Like this
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>`

Comment: remove, jquery-1.7.1.min.js two min.js files are not required. check with one

Comment: Thanks to all. it works when i remove the 1.7.1 js file....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use..

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

You were using both jQ version which will make confliction

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add two different versions of jQuery.
Use it like this:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```